# On/off transistor switch control electrical stimulation (EMS) current

Tags: transistors, circuit-design

I have a pain relief device that releases EMS current through 2 sticky pads to muscles.

I use this device by first turning the physical button on and then changing the EMS current manually from 0 - 40mA by another button. Now I have an idea what I want to replace that on/off button by a signal from the sensor. I used a circuit like this and I want to apply it to the device.

[image]

However, it doesn't work properly. I made V_out (image) replace the battery so that when the sensor signal off -> V_out = 0, on -> V_out = V. This doesn't work because every time V_out is on, I have to manually adjust the EMS current from 0.

For a second attempt, I modified ot so that the EMS current as the input V (image,) and V_out is connected to the electrode pads. This didn't work and I don't know why.

Is there any idea that can help me with it?

Edit: Clarification:

- I have a pain relief device which release EMS current (0-40mA) to muscle through 2 sticky muscle electrode.
- The device can be turned on by press a On/Off button. When it turns on, the initial current is 0mA, and we need to made adjustment (add or reduce to the desire current) through 2 button.
- I don't want to use the physical button anymore. My idea is to set up a circuit that control the device On/Off by a flex sensor. This is how I want my device works:

  - I press the On/Off button at the first time and let it on for all the time.
  - Then I adjust the current to 20mA let it be.
  - From now the device works with the current 20mA.
  - If I want to pause, I close my hand (connect by a flex sensor) and there is no current through my muscle. (Important: The device stills work with 20mA)
  - If I want to resume, I open my hand and there is current through again.
  - Press the button to turn the device off after treatment.

To achieve the goal, I used a simple transistor circuit like image and I apply it to the device.

- At the first time, I made the circuit and use the V_out of the circuit to replace the battery of the device. This means when I close my hand, there are no power for the device. This is failed because everything I close my hand, I have to press the button again to open it. This also can't adjust the current from 0 to 20mA every time reopen.
- Take the experience in the first case, I let the device open and connect circuit to the electrodes. Which means I set up like this:
  [image]
  The transistor is acting like a switch for the cathode electrode. When sensor signal off, there is no current through. When it's on, there are current back on.

However, the circuit now doesn't work. Can anybody help me to fix this?

Comment: if you have to ask, then you should not be messing with a medical device

Comment: @jsotola I don't wanna mess with it, but this is my school project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.